# What is helping Lara?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In Tomb Raider (2013) when Lara is fighting the Stormguard before her encounter with the monstrous Oni he is swept away by the wind saving her life.

Later on when she's climbing the mountains leading to the ascension ceremony several times climbing spots are opened for her by lightning and we know the weather is being controlled by Himiko in the island.

Why would Himiko help Lara when she explicitly states she's going to stop the ceremony from taking place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lara has luck and the script to help her. [Himiko](http://tombraider.wikia.com/wiki/Himiko) controls weather but is not precise with it, otherwise, she would have fried Lara on the first encounter. Here is what the wiki says about it

> Most sinister of all, Himiko's consciousness manifested itself in constantly stormy weather surrounding the island. These storms were unnatural, driven by her rage and consciousness, and would actually vary in intensity, to deliberately cause any and all ships and aircraft that ventured near the island to be wrecked or crash on it.

For the [Stalker Stormguard](http://tombraider.wikia.com/wiki/Stormguard_Stalker), it is luck again

> After a massive battle against the stormguards, she comes to face the stalker, however the strong winds blowing some wooden fences knock him out of the way for Lara to continue.

Himiko clearly knows that Lara wants to stop her from transfering her soul in Samantha's body.